# Tensor inner product vs Vector space inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, tensors, bilinear-form

How does the definition of inner product presented in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

relate to the definition presented in this video:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDcfqfWRIi8&t=108s (4:10)

I thought an inner product was a bilinear form on a vector space, but this video implies that this is a special case.

I don't understand.

Comment: The "inner product" presented is usually called the contraction. I don't think it should be called an inner product, since like you said an inner product should be a bilinear form.

Comment: The usual inner product $\langle u,v\rangle$ in orthonormal coordinates is $u^iv_i$, which is a tensor contraction. In general, contraction (with respect to a single pair of indices) *is* bilinear. If you view all other indices as constant, this is indeed an inner product.

Comment: Indeed there is a comment below the videos where someone has a confusion about the notation (The oldest comment).